# MBProgressHUD needs to be accessed on the main thread

Tags: ios, swift, mbprogresshud

Im getting this error while using MBProgessHUD. I was trying to show an Loading Indicator then my App is loading data from an Api and to stop then the data is displayed on screen.

```
func getJson(){ 
        let spinningWheel = MBProgressHUD.showAdded(to: self.view, animated: true)
        spinningWheel.label.text = "Loading"
        spinningWheel.detailsLabel.text = "Please wait a moment.."
.
. 
.
.
.
.
. 
DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.movieName.isHidden = false
                    self.movieName.text = self.movieNameLabel
                    self.movieDescription.text = self.movieDescriptionLabel
                    self.movieImage.downloadedFrom(url: url2!)
                    spinningWheel.hide(animated: true)
                }
```

Comment: where you call getJson please post all code

Comment: I call this function after the viddidload. All Code is too much :D

Comment: ok post how and where you present the vc that contains this code ??

Comment: Hi, do you call the getJson func on the main thread? because the lines where you setup your MBProgressHUD should also be called on the main thread.

Comment: I Call the func after viwdidload.. How to call the function on main thread ?

Answer (score 1):

In iOS, all UIKit method calls must be made on the main thread. Enclose all your UIkit usages in `DispatchQueue.main.(a)sync` calls, like so:

```
func getJson() {
  DispatchQueue.main.async {
    let spinningWheel = MBProgressHUD.showAdded(to: self.view, animated: true)
    spinningWheel.label.text = "Loading"
    spinningWheel.detailsLabel.text = "Please wait a moment.."
  }
  // actually get JSON
}
```

Comment: but this won't solve the root problem as this code is supposed to run in main thread and no need to wrap **DispatchQueue.main.async** in a non-suitable place

Answer (score 0):

The one suspect is that you present/push/segue to that vc from a background thread so this

```
let spinningWheel = MBProgressHUD.showAdded(to: self.view, animated: true)
```

will run inside it , so make sure to do the navigation inside the main thread , so the vc life cycle will be in correct place